# Meteor example for newbie

Tags: meteor

Following an example from a book, I have in my .js file

```
lists = new Mongo.Collection("Lists");

if (Meteor.isClient) { 
  Template.categories.helpers ({
    'Category': function(){
      return lists.find({}, {sort: {Category: 1}});
}})
```

and in my html file:

```
<body>
<div id="categories-container">
  {{> categories}}
</div> 
</body>

<template name="categories">  
<div class="title">my stuff</div>
  {{#each lists}}
    <div>
      {{Category}}
    </div>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

I have input data this data into lists which uses Category for a field  using the console:

```
> lists.insert({Category:"DVDs", items: {Name:"Mission Impossible"
,Owner:"me",LentTo:"Alice"}});
> lists.insert({Category:"Tools", items: {Name:"Linear Compression
Wrench",Owner:"me",LentTo: "STEVE"}});
```

but it doesn't output the data.

Comment: Do you have the *autopublish* package installed? How is your client subscribing to the publication from the server?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue lies in the context of your {{#each}}, you seem to be attempting to access the mongo collection itself rather specific fields through a helper function.
Check out this tutorial on spacebars, it’s a pretty good read http://meteorcapture.com/spacebars/ and also the Meteor Docs section http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/livehtmltemplates. I'm fairly new to Meteor myself but hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you use name **Category** for 2 different things.
It is the name of **template helper function** that  return an **array** of list items.
and it is the name of a **field item** inside your list.

Do the `{{#each Category}}` to run on the array returned by the **helper**

Inside the `each`, you should access the `{{Category}}` or `{{item}}` **list** items

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call your helper `lists` instead of `Category` and your code will work:

```js
Template.categories.helpers({
  lists: function () {
    return lists.find({}, {sort: {Category: 1}});
  }
});
```

`{{#each lists}}` means: Iterate over a collection cursor (the result of a find) or an array which we get by calling the helper `lists`. The naming here is somewhat confusing because `lists` also happens to be the name of the collection your are iterating over.

Inside of the `each`, the context is a `lists` document. Each document contains a `Category` field, which you are outputting inside of a `div`.

Recommended reading:

- [A Guide to Meteor Templates & Data Contexts](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/a-guide-to-meteor-templates-data-contexts/)

Answer (score 0):

check to run command : **meteor list**

it is given to you list of packages which is you used

if **autopublish** package not in the list you want to publish and subscribe your data here's simple example:

```
//in server 
 Meteor.publish('lists',function(){
    return lists.find({}, {sort: {Category: 1}}); 
 })
//in client
Meteor.subscribe('lists');
```

For More Deatails : [publish subscription](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/understanding-meteor-publications-and-subscriptions/)

Answer (score 0):

First: The function in your 'categories' helper shouldn't be between quotes (not sure if that may couse problems).

Second: You are using the `{{#each}}` loop wrong.
You are calling the 'Lists' collection, but you should call the 'Categories' helper.

```
<template name="categories">  
<div class="title">my stuff</div>
  {{#each Category}}
    <div>
      {{Category}}
    </div>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

Its very confusing your helper has the same name as the field you are calling in the `#each` loop.